# A question about draw detection in chess engines

Tags: engines, programming, draw, 50-move-rule, dead-position

Let us look at this position.

```
[FEN "4k3/8/8/p1p1p1p1/P1P1P1P1/8/8/4K3 w - - 0 1"]
```

This is obviously a draw. Analyzing this with the Stockfish engine says that it is a balanced position. However, Stockfish does not recognize that it is a draw.

Slightly rearranging the pawns, we receive a similar position that is an obvious draw.

```
[FEN "4k3/3p4/p1pPp3/P1P1P1p1/6P1/8/8/4K3 w - - 0 1"]
```

Here, Stockfish says that white has an advantage of +0.7.

Where does this miscalculation come from? I understand that draws in these positions cannot be detected from tablebases, as there are still too many pieces on the board. It seems that these special positions are called [Pawn Rams](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Pawn_Rams_(Bitboards)) or [Blockages](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Blockage_Detection).

The chess programming article about [Blockage Detection](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Blockage_Detection) provides code for detecting blockages, but I do not understand how it works.

What are the underlying factors that make draw detection so hard from a computational point of view?

Comment: Are you interested in theoretical draws or only dead positions?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon What is the difference?

Comment: A theoretical draw is a draw if both players play perfectly. For example, the starting position might be a theoretical draw (we don't know yet, and maybe never will). A dead position is a draw no matter what you play. Your examples are dead positions.

Comment: You might be interested: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32270/lichess-endgame-evaluation

Comment: I do believe the question is answerable, but it is very broad, since there are four questions asked and some of them aren't related to the others (e.g. 4 and 3)

Comment: I think the answer to the main question is obvious: Spaaaaace. Suggested experiment: Place all black pawns on their original square. If I'm right, Whites plus will go further up. Also, blockades are *notorically* difficult to detect by engines. Experiment 2: Give White another useless double pawn, what happens? What has more effect?

Answer (score 3):

I actually did the experiment and will answer now. Three main factors go into the evaluation (as king safety doesn't play the slightest role): material, space, and movability.

The effect of space is rather high at +1.4.

```
[FEN "4k3/p1p1p1p1/P1P1P1P1/8/8/8/8/4K3 w - - 0 1"]
```

Any useless doubled pawn is about +0.7, giving +4.2.

```
[FEN "4k3/p1p1p1p1/P1P1P1P1/P1P1P1P1/8/8/8/4K3 w - - 0 1"]
```

Don't underestimate agility, we're already at +5.9.

```
[FEN "4k3/p1p1p1p1/P1P1P1P1/8/8/8/P1P1P1P1/4K3 w - - 0 1"]
```

You can give White a useless bishop and scratch the 10.0 but I stop here, although it would be a fun challenge for the highest evaluation in a dead drawn position But +99.0 seems to be Lichess/Stockfish cutoff. :-)

Comment: You could also replace a pawn for another bishop (a promoted one) if you wanted to further pump up the eval

Comment: @pulsar512b - Been there, done that, Lichess doesn't even complain against 32 bishops :-) Likewise, a walled in Q or R works wonders. An engine is hopelessly optimistic: Maybe it can break out somewhere over the horizon...